# How does Android device supply internet to apps and apps become online?

Tags: networking, internet

Apps are in an offline state. Whenever I turned on data (internet), in the blink of an eye, the apps become online. In another instance, I turned on data (but I have no internet), and apps are not becoming online.

I am assuming:

1. There is something in the device that somehow figures out if my device has an internet connection or not (maybe by trying to connect to a site?)
2. If it figures out my device has an internet connection, it notifies the apps to connect to the internet.
3. Since my device got internet and the apps are notified, now we need another program(s) to share (manage) internet between the device got internet and those apps.

Now to elaborate on my question, in point 1, the thing/program which figures out whether my device has internet or not, what is it called? And in point 3, what is the program's name, and how does it share the internet with apps? Or in other words, in which way can I manage my device's internet with my user-space applications, and how do I manipulate it?

If it helps, I know (more correctly, read) DNS resolution, with destination IP address apps connected to the server.

Comment: Making a ping takes only a few seconds. Android framework provides APIs for this. Or the apps can check internet connectivity themselves. Your assumptions in point 2 and 3 don't make much sense. Why do you assume it works this way? What's the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: i am interested in knowing app(s) pre-online inner workings! especially what program of   android os process and manage internet and provide internet to apps

Comment: Or perhaps, do apps always send(s) request to their designated server when data in turned off and when data is turned on but no internet?

Comment: @IrfanLatif point 2 is a power friendly method instead of letting each app making request each second to know if the device got internet connect, in my nobby opinion

Comment: See [ConnectivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager).